# YiiPassword Extension Usage

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I extracted [YiiPassword](https://github.com/phpnode/YiiPassword)  extension into `protected/components/YiiPassword`

**main.php:**

```
    .
    .
    .
    'import'=>array(
            'application.models.*',
            'application.components.*',
            'application.components.YiiPassword.*',
            'application.helpers.*',

    ),
    .
    .
    .
```

**User.php:** (model)

```
.    
.
.
public function behaviors()
{
    return array(
        "APasswordBehavior" => array(
            "class" => "APasswordBehavior",
            "defaultStrategyName" => "bcrypt",
            "strategies" => array(
                "bcrypt" => array(
                    "class" => "ABcryptPasswordStrategy",
                    "workFactor" => 14
                ),
                "legacy" => array(
                    "class" => "ALegacyMd5PasswordStrategy",
                )
            ),
        )
    );
}
.
.
.
```

Ans also added thees three fields into **tbl_user**:

**salt** - holds the per user salt used for hashing passwords

**password** - holds the hashed password **(Exist already)**

**passwordStrategy** - holds the name of the current password strategy for this user

**requiresNewPassword** - a boolean field that determines whether the user should change their password or not

and Now i only want use **bcrypt**, how to **encode** the user password and **verify** it at user-login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

The following test successfully done, **ABcryptPasswordStrategyTest.php :**

```
<?php
Yii::import("application.components.passwordStrategy.*");
Yii::import("application.models.*");

/**
 * Tests for the {@link ABcryptPasswordStrategy} class.
 * @author Charles Pick
 * @package packages.passwordStrategy
 */
class ABcryptPasswordStrategyTest extends CTestCase
{
    public function testEncode()
    {
        $user=User::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>'user'));
        $strategy = new ABcryptPasswordStrategy();
        $strategy->getSalt(true);

        $user->password = 'pass';
        $user->save();

        $this->assertTrue($user->verifyPassword("pass"));
    }
}
```

[**more info**](https://github.com/phpnode/YiiPassword/issues/10)

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to retrieve the user and call the `verifyPassword` method! The description of this method:

> Compares the given password to the stored password for this model

So you could do something like:

```
$user = User::model()->findByPK(1);
if($user->verifyPassword("password")){
    //Password verified
}
```